# Redirect based on previous URL

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to do something and I am not to sure how I can do it!

Basically I want visitors to be re-directed to a different page if they have come from Facebook. So for example if someone shares that page I want future visitors from Facebook to that page to then be re-directed to the home page.

If I can do this through .htaccess or jQuery I am not bothered as long as it works.

Comment: What kind of CMS are you running the site on,  or Language you have written the website in?

Comment: It is a HTML website using the Editable Sites CMS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect based on referrer URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502908/redirect-based-on-referrer-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as easy as this

```
if (document.referrer !== "http://www.facebook.com") {
    document.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
}
```

or this:

```
var href = document.location.href;

if (href.indexOf("facebook.com") > 0)

document.location.href = "http://www.example.com"
```

PHP version:

```
function url(url){
      return url.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1];
    }

    function check()
    {
      var ref = document.referrer;
      if(url(ref) =='www.facebook.com')
      {

         window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via JavaScript very simply.

```
if(document.referrer.match("facebook.com")){ 
   window.location = "/";
}
```

Replace the forward slash with the proper redirection path.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.referrer !== "http://www.facebook.com") {
    document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

or in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.facebook\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/ [R]
```