# Check to see what page forwarded from

Tags: jquery

On my home page I like for it to open up only if it was
forwarded from a certain URL.

For example, `www.xyz.com/fillform` forwards to `www.abc.com`

on `www.abc.com` I like to see if I was forwarded from `www.xyz.com/fillform`
If so, I not, I would like to forward them to `www.xyz.com/fillform`.

If they were, then the page would open. Is this possible through jQuery?

Comment: Possible, but completely bypassable and hackable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect based on referrer URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502908/redirect-based-on-referrer-url)

Comment: If you have the option, and all of the pages are on the same site, this could be done very reliably on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, and as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20503028/4669143), this is NOT a secure option and should not be used to protect any kind of sensitive content.

But, to answer the question, it IS technically possible using jQuery:

```
if (document.referrer === "http://www.example.com/mypage1.html") {
    // Do something
    alert('Referred from expected page. Probably.');
}
```

If you have the option, this kind of thing can be done very reliably on the server side (PHP, etc.)