# Knowing the source of the redirect to another page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage where one of your pages has a button that has to redirect to a different page according to the page that has been redirected.

Is there a way for the redirected page to know which page has caused the redirect with javascript or html?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect based on referrer URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502908/redirect-based-on-referrer-url)

Comment: Hi @Valeklosse
I would like it to be without duplicating.

Comment: Whats wrong with `document.referrer`?

Answer (score 0):

Mozgovoy Artem is right.

```
var myReferrer = document.referrer;
```

will return the URI of the page that linked through to the current page.

---

**More Info:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer